# ¿Como cambiar tamaño de la casilla de un checkbox?

Tags: c#

buen dia, quisiera saber ¿como se puede cambiar el tamaño de la casilla de un checkbox?
estoy programando en C# con WindowsForms

Comment: estas usando vs 2017 ?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado/investigado? ¿si lo quieres hacer en el *front-end* con qué tecnología? Tu pregunta es muy amplia y puede ser cerrada. Se debería poner más detalle al respecto para saber exactamente lo que deseas lograr

Comment: solo quiero cambiar el tamaño de la casilla del checkbox, e investigado, pero realmente no entiendo el codigo, y no, estoy usando visual studio 2012

Comment: No es posible con las propiedades del Checkbox, puedes heredad de la clase y modificar tu control personalizado https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166244/how-to-increase-the-size-of-checkbox-in-winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Macx :

para qu puedas cambiar el tamaño en window form realiza este siguiente codigo.-

```
checkBox1.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
checkBox1.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16);
checkBox1.AutoSize = false;
checkBox1.Size = new Size(100, 100);
```